# How to call footer.php file in child theme from Hooks folder in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress project with a free theme and want to replace theme author name and website link. I have created child theme by a plugin named "Child Theme Configurator". Now if I check there is not any code in default footer.php file but the code is inside another footer.php but unfortunately this file is inside other folders "inc > hooks > footer.php". The code I want to edit is:

```
<?php
if( !empty($agency_lite_footer_copyright)){
echo wp_kses_post($agency_lite_footer_copyright) . " | "; 
} ?>
WordPress Theme : <a href="https://accesspressthemes.com/wordpress-themes/agency-lite" target="_blank">Agency Lite</a>
```

I have tried to copy complete inc folder in my child theme folder but it is now working when editing.

Please let me know how can I edit a file which is inside inc > hooks folder by child theme.

Comment: did you activate the child theme`?

Comment: Yes off course.

Comment: I can edit real file in parent theme it is working but I want to call it in child theme.